# Actionscript package naming and directory structure

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, class, classpath, package

I've got some actionscript which begins with:
        `package obfus_plugin{

    import org.flowplayer.model.Plugin;

    import org.flowplayer.util.Arrange;

    import org.flowplayer.model.PluginModel;

    import org.flowplayer.view.Flowplayer;

        public class obfus extends Sprite implements Plugin {`

and when I try to publish, I get the error:

```
5001: The name of package 'obfus_plugin' does not reflect the location of this file. Please change the package definition's name inside this file, or move the file. C:\flowplayer\url_secure\src\actionscript\obfus_plugin\obfus.as
```

the location of the .as file is:

```
C:\flowplayer\url_secure\src\actionscript\obfus_plugin\obfus_plugin.as
```

In my classpaths I have:

```
C:\flowplayer\url_secure\src\actionscript\obfus_plugin
```

What am I doing wrong? Did I miss a directory somewhere? All help is GREATLY appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The directory structure should match the package structure, with *classpath* as it's root.

*package{}* matches *%classpath%*.

*package A{}* matches *%classpath%/A*.

So, instead of:

```
C:\flowplayer\url_secure\src\actionscript\obfus_plugin
```

You should use, as *classpath*:

```
C:\flowplayer\url_secure\src\actionscript
```

**or** place the file in a new folder:

```
C:\flowplayer\url_secure\src\actionscript\obfus_plugin\obfus_plugin
```

**or** even use the default package in the *.as* file:

```
package {
    import [...]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried moving the file to the suggested location?

```
`C:\Documents and Settings\***\My Documents\My Dropbox\Public\obfus_plugin\obfus_plugin.as`
```

It's telling you that's where it should be placed. From the classpath root, the actionscript file should live in a nest of folders that reflects the package name.

Say you have an actionscript file with class in package X.Y.Z, the file should live in folder `%classpath%\X\Y\Z`

Comment: the location of the .as file is "C:\Documents and Settings\***\My Documents\My Dropbox\Public\obfus_plugin\obfus_plugin.as", am I missing a directory somewhere? (the editor keeps deleting the slash between "Documents and Settings" and "***")

Comment: Is the error saying that's where I should move the file, or that's where the error is?

Comment: What is the class name of the class within the file? This should match the filename.

Comment: The class name looks like: "public class obfus_plugin extends flash.display.MovieClip implements org.flowplayer.model.Plugin"